# Why does python read a dict differently on different devices and why not from top to bottom?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Today, by chance, I came across the following behaviour of python that I cannot explain. I wanted to run the following code and thought python prints the values of bundeslaender from top to bottom.

```py
bundeslaender = {
  'Baden-Württemberg',
  'Bayern',
  'Berlin ',
  'Brandenburg',
  'Bremen ',
  'Hamburg' ,
  'Hessen',
  'Mecklenburg-Vorpommern',
  'Niedersachsen',
  'Nordrhein-Westfalen',
  'Rheinland-Pfalz',
  'Saarland',
  'Sachsen',
  'Sachsen-Anhalt',
  'Schleswig-Holstein',
  'Thüringen'
}

for bundesland in bundeslaender: 
  print(f'{bundesland}')
```

But then I got the following output:

```sh
Schleswig-Holstein
Rheinland-Pfalz
Sachsen-Anhalt
Hamburg
Brandenburg
Saarland
Bayern
Berlin 
Baden-Württemberg
Bremen 
Nordrhein-Westfalen
Hessen
Niedersachsen
Thüringen
Sachsen
Mecklenburg-Vorpommern
```

I thought that was because I was using a >upiter notebook in Collab and ran the same code in the Windows terminal. There I got the following output:

```sh
Thüringen
Sachsen-Anhalt
Brandenburg
Bremen
Bayern
Baden-Württemberg
Berlin
Saarland
Schleswig-Holstein
Hessen
Hamburg
Niedersachsen
Nordrhein-Westfalen
Rheinland-Pfalz
Sachsen
Mecklenburg-Vorpommern
```

In the Windows CMD I again got a different output

```sh
Niedersachsen
Mecklenburg-Vorpommern
Hessen
Bremen
Rheinland-Pfalz
Hamburg
Berlin
Sachsen-Anhalt
Thüringen
Sachsen
Schleswig-Holstein
Brandenburg
Baden-Württemberg
Saarland
Nordrhein-Westfalen
Bayern
```

Can anyone explain to me why the output differs from program to program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not `dict`onaries, but `set`s. Those are unordered collections of unique elements. The order in which you iterator over them depends on their `hash`, which itself is almost random for each start of the interpreter (it depends on the [hash seed](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED)).

To get an ordering, use a `list` instead, so replace `{}` with `[]`:

```
bundeslaender = [
  'Baden-Württemberg',
  'Bayern',
  'Berlin ',
  'Brandenburg',
  'Bremen ',
  'Hamburg' ,
  'Hessen',
  'Mecklenburg-Vorpommern',
  'Niedersachsen',
  'Nordrhein-Westfalen',
  'Rheinland-Pfalz',
  'Saarland',
  'Sachsen',
  'Sachsen-Anhalt',
  'Schleswig-Holstein',
  'Thüringen'
]

for bundesland in bundeslaender: 
  print(f'{bundesland}')
```